# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I am using this sql query in jsp and getting invalid relational operator. I can not figure
it out why it is giving me this error.

> ```
> String gameName = request.getParameter("gameName");
> session.setAttribute("gameName",gameName);
> Statement st = con.createStatement();
> String s2 = "select stock from game where g_name '"+gameName+"' ";
> ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(s2);
> String stockDb = "";
> rs1.next();
> stockDb = rs1.getString(1);
> session.setAttribute("stockDb",stockDb);
> String stockDb1 = (String)session.getAttribute("stockDb");
> ```

Comment: Well if `gameName` contains quotes or other odd characters you could get all sorts of SQL Injection bugs - including being hacked. Don't concatenate queries like that, use `PreparedStatement` with `setString`... Never trust anything that comes in a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that there's an invalid relational operator, it's that you don't have one at all. `select stock from game where g_name {name}` is like writing a sentence without a verb. It weird. You need an `=`, `LIKE`, `IN`, etc.

Comment: thanks man, i just remembered after reading your comment that my query is missing '='. I will edit in the code later and check if it is giving the output right or not